# Best approach to get count of workitems state transitions?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I need to create a dashboard widget for Azure DevOps that shows number of work items of a specified type, that transitioned from one state to another.

It looks like the Updates endpoint is my best bet, but that means that I would have to iterate over all of the updates of workitems for the specified type and then determine if it contains the state transition I'm looking for, e.g. Closed to Open.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/updates/list?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0

The Analytics extension looked promising, but it looks like I would need to query the Revisions dataset, and that doesn't contain the old and new values.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/wit-analytics?view=azure-devops

The use case is to show the number of bugs that were closed then reopened in the last 90 days.  I thought that I would make the work item type and from and to states configurable.

Any ideas or suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: A bit more info.  The functionality I'm trying to achieve is similar to the Reactivations Report which is part of the SSRS reports.

Comment: Upvoted - exactly a question we've had asked by an external auditor today - how many tasks went back from testing; to try to understand what types of dev activities generate more in-development issues than others. Did you get anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

> Best approach to get count of workitems state transitions?

At this moment, we could not query the History with State changed from one state to another state on Web UI directly.

As workaround, **we could add a custom field in our custom process that gets set the value to `true` when workitems state change from `Closed` to `New`**:

[image]

Then add a `Rules` to set the value of the custom field to True if the workitems state change from `Closed` to `New`:

[image]

Finally, we could query the workitems with following conditions:
[image]

BTW, if you want to get those workitems which state already changed from Closed to New before use above custom filed and rules, I am afraid you have to use Rest API to query the work items that in specified type:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql

Then loop the work items list to get all revisions for every work item with Revision - List API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/revisions/list

There is a article for TFS [TFS SDK: Work Item History Visualizer using TFS API](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/243653/TFS-SDK-Work-Item-History-Visualizer-using-TFS-API), you can check it for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it through PowerBI. [Calculate time-in-state for an existing Analytics view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/create-timeinstate-report?view=azure-devops)

Or as you said iterate over all of the updates of workitems.