# How do I set up a query in Azure DevOps to tell me which items I have transferred out of my area path today?

Tags: azure-devops

Right now I have the following query:

[screenshot of query in DevOps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRYGG.png)

It's returning items I've transferred today, as I intended, but it's also returning items that were changed today by other teams (e.g., I transferred something out on Friday, but the other team changed it today, so it shows up).

Since there is no "Transfer Date", only "Changed Date" or "State Change Date", is there a better way to set this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I set up a query in Azure DevOps to tell me which items I have transferred out of my area path today?

That because you have set the Operator to `Was Ever`, which will return the work items that you have ever changed.

So, if anyone change it today, it will show up in your query result.

**To resolve this issue**, you need to change the Operator to `=`:

[image]

Now, it will not return the workitem you transferred out on Friday.

**Update:**

> the results do not stay in the query since "Changed By =" only shows
>   the LAST person to make a change. So for example, I transfer the item,
>   then someone from another team immediately comments. That work item no
>   longer shows up in the query, but I want to track it until the end of
>   the day, so I can know "x items total have been transferred out
>   today".

Indeed, this is a issue. It seems there is no such out of box way to resolve this issue at this moment.

As workaround, you could add `custom field` in our custom process, then add a `Rules` to set the value of the custom field to `True` when area path is modified.

Just like the [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57395738/best-approach-to-get-count-of-workitems-state-transitions/57407026#57407026).

Now, we could add custom field as new clause in the query, so that we could filter out the wokitems you want. However, the limitation of this method is that it can only work on newly created wokitems, and has no effect on those previously created workitems.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried using the = operator, but when I do, the results do not stay in the query since "Changed By =" only shows the LAST person to make a change.

So for example, I transfer the item, then someone from another team immediately comments. That work item no longer shows up in the query, but I want to track it until the end of the day, so I can know "x items total have been transferred out today".