# How to get sprint wise automated test cases in Azure devops system?

Tags: azure-devops, automated-tests

I am in need of getting some automation metrics like, what are the test cases automated in a specific time period in ADS.  I tried the below query.

The challenge with this query is: it is retrieving the automated test cases which were automated before this duration.  It is because their other attributes are changed like: Title, some tags etc. I was looking for some field that stores the information like(Automated Test Id, Automated Test Name, Automated Test Storage, Automation status). But I didnt' see this.  I tried to use "History" field, but that didn't work as it is not populated the automation information in history field.

Any thoughts please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNIAY.png)

Answer (score 0):

> How to get sprint wise automated test cases in Azure devops system?

At this moment, we could not query the History with State changed from one state to another state on Web UI directly.

As workaround, **we could add a custom field in our custom process that gets set the value to `true` when workitems state change from `X` to `Y`**.

Then add a `Rules` to set the value of the custom field to True if the workitems state change from `X` to `Y`.

Finally, we could query the workitems with custom field status.

You could check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57395738/best-approach-to-get-count-of-workitems-state-transitions/57407026#57407026) for some more details.

Besides, you can also try do it through PowerBI. [Calculate time-in-state for an existing Analytics view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/create-timeinstate-report?view=azure-devops).